# How can i download folder from gcp bucket using java?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

Currently, I'm using this code

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                                .setCredentials(credentials)
                                .setProjectId(projectId)
                                .build()
                                .getService();
Blob blob = storage.get(BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName));
blob.downloadTo(FilePath);
```

to download a specific file from my bucket but if I have to download a folder containing multiple files, I'm unable to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Google Cloud Platform Storage there is not such thing as folder. Instead there is a [virtual representation of them](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork) but in the reality you just have a bunch of files with "similar" names grouped in a hierarchical file tree.

i.e.

If you have `gs://bucket/folder1/folder2/objectA` and `gs://bucket/folder1/folder2/objectB`

Both files are virtually under the same folder but in the reality you just have 2 objects in your bucket with similar names

For the object A the filename is `"bucket/folder1/folder2/objectA"` and for the file b the filename is `"bucket/folder1/folder2/objectB"`

A folder is intepreted when you have a route ending in a "/" character such as `"bucket/folder1/folder2/"`

In this case, you'll need to use the [object listing method](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#storage-list-objects-java) to iterate over the objects you're interested in and individually make a call to download each one.

Comment: Yeah, listing of objects helped. Thanks!